# Usage of objective-c core data model in an swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I have an old project written in Objective-C including a complex core data model. Some new classes are already written in Swift.

Now the problem starts. How can I use the core data model (objective-c) in a swift class. The entities resp. the model classes are not available in the swift class.

I already tried to generate a swift based model. But this is not usable in Objective-C code or in case I generated both objective-c and swift models I got naming conflicts in the bridging header files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried simply importing all required Objective-C classes in the bridging header?

Comment: The bridging header is generated automatically, isn't it? Or do I have to add these classes manually?

Comment: *you* have to create the bridging header from objective-c to swift, the other way around is generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try tomorrow. But it seams to be plausible. So far I only used Swift classes in an Objective-C class.

Comment: Adding the classes to the bridging header file manually solved my problem. Thanks!
Further details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html